# how to display uploaded json file from local system on html page using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I would like to print the json values on my html page(this file is uploaded from my local system). I can able to read the file and able to get the json data format in one variable, but I am facing issueson displaying the those values on my view page.

**app.js:**

```
mainApp.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $location){
....

 $scope.loadFile = function(){


var input, file, fr;


file = input.files[0];


fr = new FileReader();


fr.readAsText(file);


var imagelines, newArrImage; 


fr.onload = function (e){


 $scope.imagelines = e.target.result;//total data in json format (Ex: [{"name":"imageurl","value":"Image1.nii"},{"name":"3d","value":"3d0"},{"name":"sliceX","value":"sliceX0"},{"name":"sliceY","value":"sliceY0"},{"name":"sliceZ","value":"sliceZ0"}])


$scope.newArr = JSON.parse($scope.imagelines);


angular.forEach($scope.newArrImage, function(data){


console.log("Data VALUES: "+data.value);//here I can get he values, like: (Ex: Image1.nii, 3d0, sliceX0, sliceY0, sliceZ0)


 });



}              


}


...


}]);
```

**html:**

```
<ul>


 <li ng-repeat="data in newArr">


 <span>{{data.value}}</span>


 </li>


 </ul>
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong to display those .json values on my html page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a plunker och jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Korven, Thanks for your reply. I have created the same at plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vCMjX5uhFgwfDp2lvbtG?p=preview .

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check jsfiddle demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/uvzLxn5g/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input type='file' /><input type="button" ng-click='loadFile()'     value="Uplaod"/>
{{ dataItems }}
</div>
</div>
```

I did some modification like assumption that data is getting in controller so please read.

Comment: Hi Biboy and Jayant Patil, Thanks for your reply. I have tried both, but still not getting the values on html page, but those are displaying on console. Here I am writing like in onload function(imagelines is having .json data) :  fr.onload = function (e){
$scope.imagelines = e.target.result;//total data in json format 
$scope.newArr = $scope.imagelines;
//$scope.newArr = JSON.parse($scope.imagelines);
angular.forEach($scope.newArr, function(data){
$scope.dataItems.push(data.value); 
});
}

Comment: @Dhana, I have updated see here http://plnkr.co/edit/bJcLfMNlFUJRYrUBN29g?p=preview

Comment: Hi Jayant Patil, Thanks for your help. Yes, It is working as per my requirement too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the newArr in Li tags to this value imagelines

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "data in imagelines" >
     <span> {{ data.value }} </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

"$scope.imagelines" already have the data of the .json file

Comment: Hi all, Finally, I have added the working fiddle here now. I really Thanks everyone for your help. Please find at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/53hfu24g/ . Thanks.